# c++ merge sort trouble

Tags: c++, mergesort

I am new to c++ and was trying develop a code for merge sort. I tested it with a sample array of size 15 but the answer put out by the code is not right. I can't figure what's going wrong. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

//two arrays, input
int initial[15] = {200,1,2,9,8,98,6,44,5,4,67,15,3,2,0};
//for output
int fin[15];

void sort(int* ini, int left, int right, int m);

//saperate the input in a recursion
void devide(int* ini, int left, int right){
     int m;

     if(left < right){
          m = (left + right) / 2;
          devide(ini, left, m);
          devide(ini, m+1, right);

          sort(ini, left, right, m);
     }
}


//sorting
void sort(int* ini, int left, int right, int m){

     //first half, start at the first element in the input array
     int first_h = left;

     //second half, start at the first element after the 
     // middle element in the input array
     int second_h = m+1;

     //index for output array
     int out = left;

     //comparing, if both half of array have element
     while(first_h <= m && second_h <= right){

          //put the smaller in the the output array
          if(initial[first_h] < initial[second_h]){
               fin[out] = initial[first_h];
              first_h++;
          }
          else{
               fin[out] = initial[second_h];
               second_h++;

          }  
          out++;   
     }

     //if one of half of input is empty, put the rest element into the 
     // output array
     while(first_h <= m){
          fin[out] = initial[first_h];
          out++;
      first_h++;
     }
     while(second_h <= right){
          fin[out] = initial[second_h];
          out++;
          second_h++;
     }
}

int main(){
     devide(initial, 0, 14);

     for(int i =0; i<15; i++){
          cout<<fin[i];
          cout<<",";
     }
     return 0;
}
```

The output of initiation[], which is fin[] is:

```
5,4,67,15,3,2,0,200,1,2,9,8,98,6,44,
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line _before_ asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Tas Here's the full stock comment for refernce: _The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger._

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ wasn't sure the best way to ask, but yes I totally stole that comment off you (I hope that's alright)! I have the entire comment for reference, but omitted the last part because this is more-or-less an mcve

Comment: @Tas Sure that's OK, since that's a common concern. I just gave you the full stuff as far I've been developing it so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one small mistake that you don't take into account is that, you are passing pointer array ini but inside the method you still use the method initial and one more thing is, you should take in a temp array that would assign the sorted values to your ini array.

So your code should look something like this

```
  void sort(int* ini, int left, int right, int m){
     int first_h = left;
     int second_h = m+1;
     int out = left;
     while(first_h <= m && second_h <= right){
          if(ini[first_h] < ini[second_h]){
               fin[out] = ini[first_h];
              first_h++;
          }
          else{
               fin[out] = ini[second_h];
               second_h++;

          }  
          out++;   
     }

     while(first_h <= m){
          fin[out] = ini[first_h];
          out++;
      first_h++;
     }
     while(second_h <= right){
          fin[out] = ini[second_h];
          out++;
          second_h++;
     }
     for(int i=left; i<out; i++)
     {
       ini[i] = fin[i];
     }
}
```

Hope this helps in understanding the algorithm better!

Comment: Yes, it work, thank you so much for that, but I hope to save the result into the array fin[], I tried to change the ini to fin. But it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: just saving it again in fin with one last for loop and you can now use fin

Comment: Why can't I save them in fin directly with  `fin[i] = temp[i];` in the first for loop?

Comment: you can do that too, updated my answer have a look

Comment: yes. but I still confusing in the last for loop. The magic thing is that if I delete it. the fin will output wrong values order. So, the correct result must come out with that for loop. Can you tell me the reason?

Comment: So I don't know how much clear are your concepts about this but I would suggest reading this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort .. may be this could clear your doubts